# set the article data categories to always be expanded

Tags: lightning-experience

Is there a way to set the article data categories to always be expanded so the selections can be viewed at a glance instead of 3 clicks deep?

[image: Expand All During Edit]

I moved my categories section to a subtab where Details is, we still have to click expand there too.

[image: Before Expanding]
[image: After expanding]